# Remote connection to Microsoft SQL Server 2014 from ASP c#

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, remote-access

I am building an web portal using ASP.NET C#. In my application, I need to retrieve some data from an remote Microsoft SQL Server Express database. I am using SQL window authentication and the sql server name and instance is S-ITS001D\TOR

This is my connecting string in c#:

```
public string connectionstring = (@"Data Source=S-ITS001D\TOR; Initial Catalog=master; Integrated Security=SSPI;");
```

It returns me the error message: 
provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server
How can I resolve this error and get to connect to the SQL server? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: check that if named pipes and tcp is enabled in your server's SQL configuration manager..

Comment: Is the server on a trusted domain? you can't use windows authentication if the domain is not trusted. The two main types of connection protocols in SQL Server are named pipes and TCP/IP. Generally you'll need to open a different port for each one.

Comment: Also have you followed any troubleshooting guides like this one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-connectivity-issues.aspx

Comment: Hi! Really appreciate for your reply. I have enabled both of Named Pipes and TCP/IP on My sql server configuration manager 2014. I have also started my sql server ad server browser. I add the TCP port 1433 to firewall exception. Is there any other configuration to do in order to get my connection to work?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thank you for your help! I solve the problem and able to connect to the remote sql server. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: @AwaisMahmood Thank you for the help :)

Comment: @Xia, most welcome.. what was the problem?

Comment: If you have time and you want to improve the community, please post specific steps.